# Sign in with Google sign in from localhost using a mobile device/other laptop to test

Tags: javascript, html, localhost, ip-address, google-signin

I'm using Google sign in for a project and all is working with https://localhost on my machine.

I want to test the website on a mobile and another laptop which is connected to the same local network.

I can connect to the site from mobile using the IP address and the path, however when I try to sign in it comes up with this error

[image]

> 400. thats an error
>
> Error: invalid_request
>
> Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain

I need a number of devices to demo it. I saw something online saying I needed to use an actual website domain and an IP address can't be used.

Is there a way around this or a best course of action?

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same problem and incase anyone is still looking for a solution here it is:

You have to use the Chrome DevTools Port Forwarding to forward your locahost port to your test device. You can find documentation on how to do that here:

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/local-server/

Comment: Could you add the instructions from your linked document to your answer, as the link may stop working at one point in the future?